# Compare two large table for unique record

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table where tableA contains 1 million records while other tableB contains 13 million records , Now I want record from tableA those are not in tableB

I used below query

```
 SELECT tableA .mergedSSN,total_unique_ssn.unique_ssn  FROM `tableA`,`tableB` WHERE tableA.mergedSSN <> tableB.unique_ssn
```

But with above query It is taking too long time ,Please help me to get record very fast.

Comment: How the tables are related and what indexes do you have

Comment: Where does `total_unique_ssn` come from?

Comment: using select .. from tbl1,tbl2 (cartesian) is very slow, probably thats why your query got stuck ;) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT tableA.unique_ssn FROM tableA
WHERE tableA.unique_ssn NOT IN (SELECT tableB.unique_ssn FROM tableB)
```

You'd need to ensure that you have both tableA.unique_ssn and tableB.unique_ssn as indexed fields.

Comment: What's the difference ?

Answer (score 2):

First of, create index by columns in each table (if you have not them yet). Then,

```
SELECT 
  tableA.mergedSSN
FROM
  tableA 
  LEFT JOIN
    tableB ON tableA.mergedSSN=tableB.unique_ssn
WHERE
  tableB.unique_ssn IS NULL
```